# Why a Python class is being updated from outside the loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm having a little problem in my `for` loop.
I wanted to create a list outside the loop and iterate an element in order to `.append` elements in the loop and then create an object.
I've followed these steps and, unfortunately, I haven't reached anything.
In the last steps: `follower_bucle_list.clear()` and `following_bucle_list.clear()` I wanted to clear all the elements of the list in order to append them next time on a new instance inside list `list_of_objects`.

PD: person is an instance of the User class

The real problem is that my `follower_bucle_list` and `following_bucle_list` updates all the elements of the `list_of_objects` instead of just one. I'm feeling like this variable changes all values.

Thank you so much.

```
list_of_objects = []
list_of_objects.append(person)
for i in range(len(person.follower_list)):
        profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, follower_list_[i])

        follower_bucle_list = []
        following_bucle_list = []

        for followee in profile.get_followers():
            follower_bucle_list.append(followee.username)

        for followee in profile.get_followees():
            following_bucle_list.append(followee.username)

        list_of_objects.append(
            User(follower_list_[i], len(follower_bucle_list) + 1, len(following_bucle_list) + 1, posts2,
                 follower_bucle_list, following_bucle_list, biography2, fullname2, web2))
        print("||     Informació descarregada de l'usuari " + follower_list_[i] + "      " + str(i + 1) + "/" + str(
            len(person.follower_list)))

        follower_bucle_list.clear()
        following_bucle_list.clear()
```

Comment: These lines (The first two lines) `list_of_objects = [];
list_of_objects.append(person)` can be simply written as `list_of_objects = [person]`

Comment: Nice!!!! Thank you

Comment: Does the variable *person* refer to a class of type *User* or are you deliberately mixing types in your list. Of course you can do that but it looks kind of odd here. Also, clearing the lists serves no purpose because you re-initialise them on each iteration of the loop. I'm going to post an answer that's untested because I have no idea what *biography2*, *fullname2*, *web2* or *posts2* refer to

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please help us help you and [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: *list_of_objects.append()* will do just that - i.e. append to the list. It will not affect any elements already in the list